# Can not get order id in woocommerce_admin_billing_fields filter hook

Tags: php, woocommerce, checkout

I have added extra field in woocommerce billing checkout fields. It is working perfectly at front end.
I want to display and edit this field at admin side in billing address. It is also working.
but my problem is I want to display this field according to order total.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_admin_billing_fields',array($this, 'wcfe_admin_billing_fields'), 10);
function wcfe_admin_billing_fields($fields) {
    global $order;
    // I am not getting $order global here
    print_r($order);
   // my conditions based on order total
    return $fields;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the `global $order;` is not available in that moment the function is called... try something like this,

```
global $post;
$order = wc_get_order( $post->ID );
```